# Adding a third dimension to my 2D array in a for loop

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a for loop that gives me an output of 16 x 8 2D arrays per entry in the loop. I want to stack all of these 2D arrays along the z-axis in a 3D array. This way, I can determine the variance over the z-axis. I have tried multiple commands, such as np.dstack, matrix3D[p,:,:] = ... and np.newaxis both in- and outside the loop. However, the closest I've come to my desired output is just a repetition of the last array stacked on top of each other. Also the dimensions were way off. I need to keep the original 16 x 8 format. By now I'm in a bit too deep and could use some nudge in the right direction!

My code:

```
excludedElectrodes = [1,a.numberOfColumnsInArray,a.numberOfElectrodes-a.numberOfColumnsInArray+1,a.numberOfElectrodes]
matrixEA = np.full([a.numberOfRowsInArray, a.numberOfColumnsInArray], np.nan)
for iElectrode in range(a.numberOfElectrodes):
    if a.numberOfDeflectionsPerElectrode[iElectrode] != 0:
        matrixEA[iElectrode // a.numberOfColumnsInArray][iElectrode % a.numberOfColumnsInArray] = 0

for iElectrode in range (a.numberOfElectrodes):
    if iElectrode+1 not in excludedElectrodes:
        
        """Preprocessing"""
        
        # Loop over heartbeats
        for p in range (1,len(iLAT)):
            # Calculate parameters, store them in right row-col combo (electrode number)
                    matrixEA[iElectrode // a.numberOfColumnsInArray][iElectrode % a.numberOfColumnsInArray] =  (np.trapz(abs(correctedElectrogram[limitA[0]:limitB[0]]-totalBaseline[limitA[0]:limitB[0]]))/(1000))

                    # Stack all matrixEA arrays along z axis
                    matrix3D = np.dstack(matrixEA)
```

Comment: Do the 2D arrays have the same shapes for every iteration of the loop? Also, use `[i,j]` for indexing, not `[i][j]` , as this slices the array twice.

Comment: Yes they have the same 16 x 8 shape, it has to be this shape because it corresponds with my electrode locations on the array that I used to get the measurements. Thanks for the feedback, I've changed it and it works better indeed.

Answer (score -1):

This example snippet does what you want, although I suspect your errors have to do more with things not relative to the `concatenate` part. Here, we use the `None` keyword in the array to create a new empty dimension (along which we concatenate the 2D arrays).

```
import numpy as np

# Function does create a dummy (16,8) array
def foo(a):
    return np.random.random((16,8)) + a

arrays2D = []
# Your loop
for i in range(10):
    # Calculate your (16,8) array
    f = foo(i)
    # And append it to the list
    arrays2D.append(f)

# Stack arrays along new dimension
array3D = np.concatenate([i[...,None] for i in arrays2D], axis = -1)
```

Comment: Hi Lith, thank you kindly for your suggestion! The code is working, but from the variance outcome I suspect there is indeed an error coming from other parts of the code that I will have to address first. Appreciate your suggestion a lot!